# Chrome hide an element on scroll after orientationchange

Tags: css, google-chrome, mobile

I'm facing a problem I can't figure out how to solve. I'm almost sure this is a Chrome bug since in other browsers it works like a charm but I want to be sure. On my [website](http://aurelio.audero.it), developed using a mobile first and responsive design approach, I have a menu that uses the [Left Nav Flyout](http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/web/responsive-nav-patterns/#left) pattern. On Tablets and desktops, I show it full width.

When I load the website on my smartphone (specifically an Android device) using Chrome in Portrait mode, once I rotate the device (passing in Landscape mode) and start to scroll the page, as soon as I reach the menu position, the latter magically disappears. What is really strange is that if you try to click the space that now is completely white, you can see that the links are actually there. I tried to use the inspector to find the problem but didn't succeed.

So, wow can I solve the problem? Anyone else had this issue before? If you know it's a bug, I'm glad to add a temporary workaround as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a real solution but a reasonable workaround. Of course, I still hope that someone will explain what's the cause of this issue and how to solve it.

In the meantime, I found that the problem occurs because the menu, 240px wide, is completely out of the viewport. In fact, as soon as I changed the `margin-left` to 239.5px the menu didn't disappear anymore.